# Partition on SQL with random sampling

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a **database** like this:

[image]

How can I get a **random sample** of for example 2 rows of New York City and 3 random rows of London? Do some one know a simple and short code for this?

I am thinking of using `row () over (partition by City order by City)` but how to move on?

Comment: "random sample" and your <2 of New York, 3 of London> requirement do not match. So what is your actual goal? Do you want a random 50% of rows from each group (i.e., City)?

Comment: I just want 2 rows with the City of New York and 3 rows of the City of London displayed. But this rows need to be choosen randomly.

Answer (score 3):

One option uses `row_number()` and `new_id()`.

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by city order by newid()) rn
    from mytable t
    where city in ('New York City', 'London')
) t
where rn <= case city
    when 'New York City' then 2
    when 'London' then 3
end
```

`row_number()` randomly ranks record having the same city. Then, in the outer query, we select the required number of records per city with a conditional expression.

This gives you a *random* pick. If you want *any* record(s), then no need for `newid()`: just use `order by (select null)`, which is cheaper.

Comment: Thanks, It works. Are their are other method without subqueries? I am not a big fan of subqueries. What about this TABLESAMPLE method?

Comment: @Freddy: other approaches using `union` require scanning the table multiple times (once per city), so they are less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tablesample](https://afana.me/archive/2010/12/01/random-rows-efficiently-in-sql-server.aspx/).

```
(select somefields from yourtable tablesample(2 rows) where city = 'New York City')
 union 
(select somefields from yourtable tablesample(3 rows) where city = 'London')
```

Comment: Yes this is true. But the results amount differ always. I do not get always the demaned rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use also this code, without partition:

```
select * from 
(select Top 2 City, Unit_price, newID() as t from Sales where City = 'Naypyitaw'
order by newID()) as tt

union 

select * from (
select Top 3 City, Unit_price, newID() as t from Sales where City = 'Yangon'
order by newID()) as tt
```